# HTML Dropdown Menu Previously Selected Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am using PHP and HTML to construct a HTML table that generates with a PHP while loop. I am populating a HTML dropdown menu with all of the distinct portfolio names in my mySQL database. To do this I am doing:

```
$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT PORT FROM CELP";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_query($default));
if ($result2)
{
  {
echo "<select id='port' name='port'>";
while ($col = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo "<option value='" . $col[0] . "'>" . $col[0] . "</option";
}
echo "</select>";
} }
```

This works but whenever I submit my form the dropdown value I selected resets to the default first value. How can I put the "selected" tag in the option that was last submitted, and that one only. P.S. I use $_GET and the variable name for that is port, so it shows the currently selected portfolio in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
while ($col = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    if(shouldBeSelected)
    {
       echo "<option selected="selected" value='" . $col[0] . "'>" . $col[0] . "</option";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $col[0] . "'>" . $col[0] . "</option";
    }
}
```

Do it for the one that should be selected. You just need to use the `selected` property.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to dynamically change which one is selected. The options are constructed with a "while" loop so I need one line of code to be able to generate all of the options yet know which one to select.

Comment: @user1650487 that is exactly what this will do just put this code in your `while loop`...

Comment: @user1650487 there just updated it you should still put it in the `while` loop just check if the element matches the element in the url if it does then set the `option` `selected`...

Comment: Tried with no luck:

while ($col = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

if($port==$col[0])
{
   echo "<option selected='selected' value='" . $col[0] . "'>" . $col[0] . "</option>";
}
else
{
    echo "<option value='" . $col[0] . "'>" . $col[0] . "</option>";
}

}
echo "</select>";

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. There was just a syntax error on my part. Thanks!

Comment: @user1650487 no problem glad I could help!